# I want to access element in list of arrays of int64

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, arraylist, numpy-ndarray

I have this data:

```
l = ['10 20 10 36 30 33 400 400 -1 -1', 
    '100 50 50 30 60 27 70 24 -2 -2 700 700', 
    '300 1000 80 21 90 18 100 15 110 12 120 9 900 900 -3 -3',
    '30 90 130 6 140 3 -4 -4 1000 1000']
                                                                                            
l = [e.split() for e in l]
```

I've created the following variable, which is a list of arrays of int64:

```
time = [np.array(time[2::2], dtype=int) for time in l]
```

I would like my time arrays values to be sorted and only contain values that are not within 0-50.
so I did the following:

```
for array in range(len(time)):
    for row in time[array]:
        for element in row:
          if element < 0 or element > 50:
          element = False
          print("Error: Index {:.2f} in time is out of range".format(element))
```

I got this output:

```
 'numpy.int64' object is not iterable
```

I would like this output:

```
Array of int64 [10 30 False False]
Array of int64 [50 60 70 False False]
Array of int64 [80 90 100 110 120 False  False]
Array of int64 [130 140 False False]
```

Comment: I dont get your output, since you said you want values within 0-50

Comment: Is there supposed to be `if element >= 50:` in the loop?

Comment: `time[array]` is a row, not a 2D array.

Comment: I think you want `for row in time:`, you don't need the `array` variable.

Comment: Ok, i forgot something in my for loop – so i have edited my question now I should have everything; what I meant is I want my array/row to only contain values that are not withing 0-50, if else value/int = False

Answer (score 1):

First a few small pointers:

1. Please don't use 1 letter variable names, unless they are for indexing (i, j, k etc..), but proper full names.
2. In python you can directly iterate over the elements, so there is no need for the `range` function and indexing.

The problem is that you are trying to iterate over a single number

```
for array in range(len(time)):
    # time[array] = [10 30 400 1] on first turn, so row gets value 10
    # Since we are directly iterating over the elements.
    for row in time[array]:  
        for element in row:  # <--- Row is here an integer value (10) on the first turn.
            if element < 0 or element > 50:
                element = False
                print("Error: Index {:.2f} in time is out of range".format(element))
```

Now I slightly rewrote your begin to use a few more descriptive names (feel free to ignore it). But this was my code start.

```
import numpy as np

data = [
    '10 20 10 36 30 33 400 400 -1 -1',
    '100 50 50 30 60 27 70 24 -2 -2 700 700',
    '300 1000 80 21 90 18 100 15 110 12 120 9 900 900 -3 -3',
    '30 90 130 6 140 3 -4 -4 1000 1000'
]

data = [row.split() for row in data]
time = [np.array(time[2::2], dtype=np.int) for time in data]
```

Then the following code:

```
for row in time:
    elements = []
    nr_false = 0
    for element in row:
        if 0 <= element <= 50:
            nr_false += 1
        else:
            elements.append(element)

    elements.sort()
    elements.extend([False] * nr_false)
    print("Array of int64", elements)
```

produces the output:

```
Array of int64 [-1, 400, False, False]
Array of int64 [-2, 60, 70, 700, False]
Array of int64 [-3, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120, 900]
Array of int64 [-4, 130, 140, 1000]
```

#### Explanation

We are going to add new data that is either an integer or a boolean (`False`). If we try to do this using `np.int` types, the boolean value will be represented as `0`. Therefore we create an intermediate list that will maintain all the valid values and count the number of invalid elements.

Since in your example the `False` elements were sorted at the end I choose to ignore the `False` addition until the last point and sort the elements first.

Comment: Thank you thymen, this is nit exactly the output i am looking for since i want my variable in variable  exploarer also to have the same output and not only printed in console. But this is soooo close. I would appreciate  i you could help me further – below you’ll  what i have coded so far, either way i appreciate  your time and help!

Comment: If you want to store the output variables you can create another list, similar to `elements` but outside the loop and append the final answer to that. Is that what you are looking for? Also note that it is not possible to create an array of int64, using `False` values. Since `False` is not an integer, it will be represented by a `0`, when converting to `np.int64`.

Answer (score 0):

I am confused with your explanation and the example output.

As Thymen pointed in his answer, you cannot have strings or boolean type values in a numpy array of int type.

Since you want the values that are beyond the required range to be different from the values within the range, you can replace the values outside the required range with abnormal values.

Therefore, values that are not between 0-50 will be replaced with 9999999999 (because we can't have False or "False" in a numpy array of int type).

For example, -1 will be replaced with 9999999999 or 70 will be replaced with 9999999999 because they are not

I have considered your example for the code below:

```
l = ['10 20 10 36 30 33 400 400 -1 -1', 
    '100 50 50 30 60 27 70 24 -2 -2 700 700', 
    '300 1000 80 21 90 18 100 15 110 12 120 9 900 900 -3 -3',
    '30 90 130 6 140 3 -4 -4 1000 1000']
                                                                                            
l = [e.split() for e in l]

time = [np.array(time[2::2], dtype=np.int64) for time in l]

for row in range(len(time)):
    for element in range(len(time[row])):
        
        # I didn't understand your output requirement. You said you 
        # wanted to have values that are not withing 0-50 but the 
        # example output shows 10, 30 and also 60 and 140.
        
        # So, edit the below condition according to your requirement
        if time[row][element] >=0 and time[row][element] <= 50: 
            time[row][element] = 9999999999

    time[row].sort()
    
time
```

This gives:

```
[array([        -1,        400, 9999999999, 9999999999], dtype=int64),
 array([        -2,         60,         70,        700, 9999999999],
       dtype=int64),
 array([ -3,  80,  90, 100, 110, 120, 900], dtype=int64),
 array([  -4,  130,  140, 1000], dtype=int64)]
```

It alters the original array and it looks like below in the variable explorer.
[image]